# Getting Data in registers (MIPS Bare)?

Tags: assembly, mips, bare

Can someone explain the concept of getting strings (data) into registers. I simply want to print a line from .data onto the screen. It seems so easy but I can't understand exactly what I'm doing.

Here's some code:

```
.data 
 input: .asciiz "Welcome to class 4"

.text
  main:
     addi $v0, $0, 4
     lui $v0, prompt 
     lui $a0, $v0 
     syscall
```

This is in bare (as the question mentions), so I don't have pseudo instr. My current thinking is I'm using addi to replace the "li" pseudo instruction. I'm adding 4 into register $v0 for a bit offset (which I'm not entirely sure why I need to do this). I was told by a TA this was necessary. I'm then loading the data into $v0 and from $v0 into $a0. Then syscall for printing onto the console.

What am I doing wrong and how can I better understand these concepts?

Comment: Look at the assembler output for `la $a0, input` and note how it uses `lui` and `ori` to construct a 32-bit address out of high and low halves.  You can then do that yourself.

Comment: Update: I think I found where my prompt is stored in memory (0x10000030 or 0x1030?) so I changed the code to:     addi $v0, $0, lui $a0, 0x1030. This compiles and when I run it i get a 'memory out of bounds error' and it prints (null) (null) to the screen. Maybe this can help you guys explain what exactly I'm not comprehending

Comment: Oh wow, i didn't even know that was a feature in QTspim. I still would like to understand it though

Comment: `addi $v0, $0, 4` is not adding a bit of offset. It's adding `$0` and value 4. The register `$0` has also alias `$zero`, and it's special MIPS CPU register, which ignores all writes into it, and all reads will see value zero in it. So that `addi` is doing `$v0 = 4` by "exploiting" `addi` instruction. The value 4 is for the `syscall` implementation code, which will check `v0` for it's value, and pick service to execute according to it, 4 is [print string](https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/mars/Help/SyscallHelp.html) service. Then that implementation will use value in `a0` as mem addr

Comment: but I don't understand the remaining `lui $v0, prompt `, that doesn't make sense, `v0` should stay `4` for the "print string" service. The `lui` would be expected with `a0` register, to set up the string address into `a0`. Are you sure you posted correct and working source code? Also you are allowed in both SPIM and MARS to use pseudo instructions, so write your example first with them, as you will find in many tutorials, then check in debugger how the pseudo instructions are implemented with native ones, like bigger constants are loaded by using some combination of `lui/ori/addi/...`, etc.

Comment: and the `a0` doesn't contain string as string, but it contains number, which represents memory address of first character. Memory addresses on SPIM MIPS machine are 32 bit integers, i.e. they fit into single register nicely, usually addresses in `.data` section looks like `0x100000030` or similar (you can find in MARS (similar sim to SPIM) in setting machine memory map). The real "print string" work is done in the simulator implementation of `syscall` service, unfortunately you get not even glimpse of how such things are usually implemented in assembly :/